# Bringing specific Jdialog to front when having multiple jdialogs in one application

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have multiple JDialogs in my application stored in a map. These JDialogs are all have

```
setModel(false);
```

When these dialogs are out of focus and I want to bring a specific JDialog toFront all JDialogs come toFront. I want the specific Jdialog to come to front and want the other JDialogs to remain in back.

```
     HashMap<String, JDialog> jDialogMap = getJDialogMap();
       String key = "jd1";
       JDialog specificJDialog= jDialogMap.get(key);

        if (specificJDialog== null){
             specificJDialog= new JDialog();
             specificJDialog.setModel(false);
             specificJDialog.setVisible(true);
             jDialogMap.put("jd2", specificJDialog);
        } else {
             specificJDialog.toFront();
             return;
       }
```

This code brings all the JDialogs toFront having the specificJDialog on top of the stack.

```
getJDialogMap();
```

This Method only returns a HashMap nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem I think it is worth sharing it.

Solution: Creating multiple JDilogs in an application with default constructor i.e.    new JDialog() will result in a shared frame as the parent of each JDialog which will cause these kind of problems. So I used the overloaded constructor    new JDialog(new JFrame()) to have separate parent for each JDialog and that solved my problem.

Comment: wow this saved my day. I had two modal dialogs and the wrong one would be in front. `toFront()` didn't help, `requestFocusInWindow` didn't help - having a different (even fake) parent did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

use requiredDialogObject.requestFocusInWindow();

whenever u need focus on the specific dialog

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. After opening the JDialog my main application window just requested the focus again, moving the JDialog window to the background, which was annoying. I experimented with modal() and toFront() methods, which both didn't work out for me, since modal() just prevented user interaction completely (outside of that JDialog) and toFront() also has effect on windows outside my application (by using it inside of a timer method, see below).

To keep the window in front of the main application I used a timer method, which was fired every 300 ms and just keeps requesting the focus by using the requestFocus() method.

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
Timer timer = new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        requestFocus();
    }
});
timer.start();
```